how to attach baluster on deck
2nd floor porch railing had 1x4s as decorative finish but we had numerous wasp hives under them so I removed them. Some of the balusters were only attached to the 1x4s and are not long enough to reach to the top board.
I have bought weather-treated replacement balusters to fill in the spots.
2 questions:

I have read that they are too wet to paint at 1st. If this is true how long do i have to wait before painting them white?

What is the best way to attach them? It does not seem like they were attached at all other than by the nails through the boards I removed. Some of the remaining ones can be pushed and move a little. I cannot get under then bottom without removing the entire thing.  Can I use some kind of adhesive? Do I need to take off the top board and put nails/screws in from the top?  See picture.



Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.
Eric

Please note that adhesive by itself will not hold the blusters in strongly enough to serve as a safety barrier. Physical metal fasters are needed.
You can try pocket screws going up and down. You will need some hand or C clamps and outdoor wood glue to complete this job.
Drill the pockets in the new balusters with a jig:

Source
Then use pocket screws to screw the balusters to the railings:

Source
Here's how the pocket screw looks when screwed in:

Source
Then glue and clamp down pocket screw plugs to cover the holes left by the pocket screw jig:

Source
Sand the plugs flush after the glue dries, then prime & paint the new balusters.
(I am not affiliated with the products shown, but I would endorse the jig, as I own one and it works great.)
